# Prompt is not working

Tags: javascript

So this is the code I have and that is called upon when clicking on a page in my nav-bar and the prompt box does come up and ask for input but no matter what I type in nothing happens:

```
function AlertFunction() {
  var person = prompt("Please Enter Password to enter Private Chat");

  if (person === Python) {
    window.location.pathname = 'index.1.html';
  } else {
    alert("Sorry you do not have access to this page");
  }
}
```

I'll put website here and try to keep it online that way you can view the page if you would like: https://project-js-imthatguy.c9users.io/index.html

Comment: Press F12 (on windows) to open debug  console. I'm guessing it'll say that `Python` is wrong and should be `"Python"` with quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value from a [`prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) is always a string. If you want to test the response against the actual value of "Python", it needs to be in quotes. Also, remember that strings are case-sensitive, so "python" doesn't equal "Python".

If `Python` is not supposed to be the literal value, then it is a variable and you don't seem to have declared or initialized that anywhere.

```js
function AlertFunction() {
  var person = prompt("Please Enter Password to enter Private Chat");

  // Strings are case-sensitive
  if (person === "Python") {
    window.location.pathname = 'index.1.html';
  } else {
    alert("Sorry you do not have access to this page");
  }
}

AlertFunction();
```

Comment: @ImThatGuy Your welcome, don't forget to upvote and mark as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Python` is an undeclared variable. When the JS engine tries to read it to compare it to `person`, it throws a reference error and aborts the script.

You need to surround it with quotes to make it a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

Python is not defined, I am assuming you meant to write "Python"

And you shouldn't store passwords inside your HTML/JS or Client side in general. EVER.

Comment: how else should i place it then

Comment: You will need to do that on your database/server side and passwords in general are tricky business and should be hashed and salted for maximum security